# Raw field info in Designer client search

Tags: lotus-notes

I was searching for a field we're doing away with in one of our databases and found a number of forms on which the field is no longer used, but show search hits.

```
<item name='Edit_Date' summary='false' sign='true'>
<rawitemdata type='400'>
AAAAAAAAAAA=
</rawitemdata></item>
```

They'd done clean up in this regard before, I assume, and this likely represents documents on which the field used to exist. While I know that editing the DXL could corrupt the design, I might clean those out in the DXL just for completeness. So, two questions:

1. Am I right about the source of the apparent "false positives"?
2. Do you think it worth the risk to delete those false positives in DXL?

Thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 1):

If you have fields in documents that are no longer used in the design (and you're sure you'll never need the data back), then just run a formula agent against all documents:

```
FIELD Edit_Date := @DeleteField
```

Comment: RH, they are showing up on the form design. They do also exist on the documents, but I'm curious why it shows on the DXL of the form design when it's no longer on the form. I assume it's because it used to be on the form. It puzzles me that it would stay, even in this obscure manner, on the design at all.

Comment: It's strange that it stays there, and I'm guessing that it's harmless to delete it, but I'd definitely keep a backup close at hand.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not showing up in designer and not being saved in the document, then it is possible corruption.

The "AAAAAAAAAAA=" isn't corruption. When Notes converts NSF design elements into DXL, where it can't map something 100% it creates a binary representation.

This is to allow a 100% round trip for the DXL data.

Deleting the element should have no issues when saving, except that the field will be gone.

Comment: But the field is "already gone". I'm sure that this ghosting isn't something new with ND8, but that we just couldn't see these ghost fields that had already been deleted.